# RadTreeList within RadFilter

Tags: linq-to-entities, radtreelist

I have an object which is returned from Linq to Entity Framework and I can list its data in a **RadTreeList** but when I try to filter its data within **RadFilter**, there is no such a way to integrate the Filter's result into object which I just get from Linq to Entity.

Do you have any way to filter data in RadTreeList?

Answer (score 0):

My friend recommended me that

1. I need to have another SqlClient DataSource, so that I can inject
   result of RadFilter into this DataSource and apply it to
   RadTreeList. But it still has another problem with RadTreeList since
   the Result doesn't display correctly as what I expect (some record
   has parentID but the record of this parentID is not found in filter,
   so it displays nothing).

My another solution:

1. I allow to filter only by the name of Last child items in
   RadTreeList.
2. I create a recursive stored-procedure to search all parents of the
   child items.
3. Link of Recursive SQL Statement
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx
4. My result will display in Hierarchical as what I want it to be.